# File copy-on-write in Java?

Tags: java, linux, copy-on-write

I'm using brtfs, and I'd like my Java program to copy a set of large files copy-on-write.

In other words, what's the equivalent of `cp --reflink=auto` in some library that hopefully exists and somebody has heard of, so they can tell me? :-)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a Java-specific API to my knowledge, because this is a rather specific, OS-dependent, and filesystem-dependent feature. However, with the help of a library that can issue ioctls (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/helins/linux-io.java) which I have no affiliation with and found by googling), you can issue the [`ficlonerange` ioctl](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ficlonerange.2.html).

To invoke it you'll need to put together a struct:

```
           struct file_clone_range {
               __s64 src_fd;
               __u64 src_offset;
               __u64 src_length;
               __u64 dest_offset;
           };
```

It's a bit roundabout in Java, but as an example, you should be able to do this as follows using the linked library:

1. [allocate a direct buffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect%28int%29),
2. populate its parameters (being careful to properly deal with machine endianness); you'll need to open FDs as well.
3. [get a pointer with `Native.getDirectBufferPointer`](https://javadoc.io/static/net.java.dev.jna/jna/5.12.1/com/sun/jna/Native.html#getDirectBufferPointer-java.nio.Buffer-)
4. Invoke the ioctl with [this](https://github.com/helins/linux-io.java/blob/main/src/main/java/io.helins.linux.io/io/helins/linux/io/LinuxIO.java#L119).
5. error-check the result and take appropriate action if the ioctl fails or is not supported.

If that seems too brittle, consider writing a C or C++ library that calls the ioctl and has a more convenient API, and then call into it via JNI.

Comment: Right. I had been hoping this code exists somewhere and I don't have to write it.

Comment: @JohannesErnst Somehow missed this comment at first, so my apologies for the delay in responding - I don't have any knowledge of a prewritten library for specifically this. Either you're going to have to write it, or you'd have to find a library (and library recommendations are off-topic for Stack Overflow). Short of me creating, publishing, and maintaining a library for an ioctl that doesn't even exist on my non-BTRFS machine, the best I can do is to tell you the steps to take, which I've done to the best of my ability. I'm not sure how else I can help here as far as addressing that comment.